# timer not update method not work proper

Tags: java, timer

i want to update data() method to each 500ms but my below timer update data() method more than 4 or 5 sec.thanking you..

```
class RemindTask extends TimerTask {
    public void run() {
            try {

                data();

            } catch (UnsupportedCommOperationException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(test2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(test2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (TooManyListenersException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(test2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

    }
```

and timer trigger method is..

```
 private void okActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                   

if(evt.getSource()==ok)
{
    bul=true;
    if(new communication().bul1==false)
    {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(test2,"GPS CONNECTE");

    }
    //System.out.print(bd.get);
   timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new RemindTask(), 500); 

}
```

Comment: Did not get your question. Can you re-frame it again ?

Comment: i writes data() method which i want continue update with 500ms interval. and i write above code for it but not work proper this code up date my data() method each 4 sec but in argument i entered 500ms only why it happend

Answer (score 1):

You are using wrong version of `schedule` method. The second argument is **delay**, not interval. You can refer the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) for details.

`ScheduledExecutorService` is better than `Timer`, below is a code sample:

```
ScheduledExecutorService ses = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
ses.scheduleAtFixedRate(new RemindTask(), 0, 500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

And your `RemindTask` should implement `Runnable` interface:

```
class RemindTask implements Runnable {
  public void run() {
  // ...
  }
}
```

Also please read the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html).